# Discord.js Remove Role Error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

> Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Supplied
>   parameter was neither a Role nor a Snowflake.

Please Help me

The Code

```
const rolename = args.join(\` \`);
message.channel.send(\`${message.author.username} Left his  clan\`);
let r = message.member.roles.filter(a => {    a.name.includes('clan')  });  
message.member.removeRole(r)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.filter()` send you an array and you use this array with `removeRole()` which is a function takes a string in parameter.

Use `removeRoles()` instead.

Doc [here](http://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=removeRole).

Comment: Okay Thank you very much